# Jquery inArray() method to find a class in a Jquery Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Suppose I have a Jquery Object `$('.class0 .class1 .class2...')`.  I want to check if a class `.classX` is in this object.  How can I do this?  I don't think `inArray()` is not adapted

In the same time, just to make things clearer for me, if I have a Jquery Object `$('.class0, .class1, .class2, ...')` if I want to check if a class `.classX` is in this object, I should use `inArray()` method, right?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to know for sure? I mean, if it's required for that class to be existent in your result set, then you should use a selector that only returns elements with that class...

Comment: Do you need to check if `.classX` was in the selector even if there are no matching elements of `.classX`?  It's easy to find if your jquery object contains any elements of `classX` but a different question if you need to know if the selector contained the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

```
var hasClass = $obj.hasClass("classX");
```

Notice there no dot (`.`) character prefixing `classX`.

Comment: this is returning false var tmp = $('.class0 .class1 .class2');
    alert($(tmp).hasClass('.class2'));

Comment: @user1611830, notice there's no dot (`.`) prefixing `class2`. It's `hasClass('class2')` not `hasClass('.class2')`

Comment: @user1611830 BTW, you don't need to do `$(tmp)` in your example. `tmp` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: Great thank you ! Where can I find some docs about Jquery objects and methods, i need to understand better !

Answer (score 6):

If there is a set of elements in jQuery object, you can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var isInside = $(".class0, .class1, .class2, ...").filter(".classX").length > 0;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting more upvotes than `.hasClass()` and `.is()`

Comment: Using filter, you can still returning set of objects

Comment: The OP didn't say he wanted a set of objects with the specified class. He simply wants to know if an object with the class exists.

Comment: He could also do `$(".classX", this);` inside the context of the first jQuery object to get the "filtered" results as well.

Comment: @crush I'm not sure that you are right. `$(".class0 .class1 .class2")` will return an element with class `class2`, hence it doesn't make any sense to check if the element has class `class0` or whatever. I guess the OP misspelled. There should be commas in the selector.

Comment: @VisioN It returns a jQuery object, not an element. `$(selector, obj)` is functionally the same as `obj.filter(selector)`. Did you try it?

Comment: @crush To be precise an element has className, not a jQuery object. **NO.** The functionality is different. The context part is transformed to `obj.find(selector)`.

Comment: @VisioN are we talking about something completely different here? $(selector) does NOT EVER return an element, and does not have a className attribute. It returns a jQuery object or collection of jQuery objects (still a jQuery object). I think you are highly confused.

Comment: @crush Oh, yeah. That's exactly about me :) I guess you need to re-read our conversation carefully.

Comment: @VisioN I think you misread somewhere. Nowhere does the OP, or myself, imply or state that he is searching to check for `class2` within the results of the initial selection. He is searching for `classX`, which, could in fact be `class129429` for all we know.

Comment: @crush All right. Just answer my question. What elements does the following selector match: `$(".class0 .class1 .class2")`?

Comment: @crush - The OP has accepted hasClass as the right answer, and using a filter to filter out a certain class from the collection and then checking the length of the result would do exactly the same thing, so this answer does what is asked in my opinion. As for the comma, that is obviously a typo in the question, otherwise what would be the point ?

Comment: @adeneo The point here is that `$(".class0 .class1 .class2")` and `$(".class0, .class1, .class2")` will return *absolutely* different results.

Comment: Yes, and for the first one checking for a certain class would'nt make much sense as it selects `.class2` inside `.class1` inside `.class0`, and the OP has now changed the question as well ?

Comment: @adeneo And that is what I was talking about :)

Comment: In the OP's second example of the jQuery selector, he used the commas appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.class0, .class1, .class2').is('.class2');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/DSvYH/1/)